# Cannot import mattews_corrcoef from sklearn 0.19.1

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn

I use `from sklearn.metrics import mattews_corrcoef`, but get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name mattews_corrcoef

Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: There's a spelling mistake in your import. Its `matthews_corrcoef` with an `'h'`. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html

Comment: Yes. Thank you, Regolith!

Answer (score -1):

do this (you had a spelling error):
`from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef`